# PHP curl postfields without value

Tags: php, curl

I was wondering what to put for the post fields in the event of the name of an input does not have a coresponding value? e.g:

the button/image here:

and this hidden input:

They both have names but no value, so I'm not sure how to post these fields in curl since it would be like this:

scroll= ??

or

buttonName=??

since they do not have values, how should I handle this when making the string to pass to the CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS?

Answer (score 1):

If you mean the parameters are empty, as in a form with no content in the input fields, the post data should look like `scroll=&buttonName=`.